# Black screen after Flashed ROM build from AOSP source

Tags: 4.3-jelly-bean, samsung-galaxy-tab-2-7, open-source

I everyone. I have compiled Android 4.3.1 for my device (Samsung Galaxy TAB 2 7.0). After flashed the compiled zip file my tablet stuck on samsung logo. 
After analyzed the Logcat i have noticed this part :

```
I/SurfaceFlinger(  109): SurfaceFlinger's main thread ready to run. Initializing graphics H/W...
D/libEGL  (  109): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
D/libEGL  (  109): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
D/libEGL  (  109): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
F/libc    (  109): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 136
```

I am not sure but i think my problem is linked to SurfaceFlinger. My problem is SurfaceFlinger can someone tell me how to fix it ?

**PS : In case someone ask for it, here's my full logcat : http://charly1811.ga/logcats/logcat.txt or https://gist.github.com/charly1811/7488508/raw/60cc1b4795159efb3a4daaf2c05d437d73e7aeac/logcat**

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Probably the kernel is missing the kernel GPU driver needed by the userspace GPU driver. Did you remember to build and flash a kernel as well as a system image?

Comment: The GPU Driver is there (/system/lib/modules/pvrsrvkm_sgx540_120.ko) . I have flashed the kernel image. After flashed zip files . I used heimdall to flash *img files generated during the build

Comment: Is it loaded as well? `lsmod` will tell you.

Comment: yes . The output of lsmod is: pvrsrvkm_sgx540_120 394802 0 - Live 0x00000000

Comment: Trying to follow your link, I couldn't reach the server "charly1811.ga."

Comment: @dan the link works here

Comment: If you can't see the logcat you can get it from here https://gist.github.com/charly1811/7488508/raw/60cc1b4795159efb3a4daaf2c05d437d73e7aeac/logcat

Comment: anyone can help ?